Regular expression match for specific string styles (which has number and strings between specific characters 【 】)
I want to make a regular expression that would match the following citations.
【digit(s)†strings】 or 【digit(s):digit(s)†strings】

Here are some examples the regex should match:
【4†BD Vid Texts for it 091224.docx】
【4:1†xShort Dashboard Texts.pdf】
【40†source】
...

I found a regex that worked with the last one above. But it doesn't work with the others.
【\d+(:\d+)?+†source】
To clarify, I am getting like the below response when API calls and I want to remove those special citations from the result.
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 【4†BD Vid Texts for it 091224.docx】 .
Lorem Ipsum 【40†source】 .

The result I want will look like the below.
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum.


@cyberbrain suggested this regex. Thanks for your
suggestions. 【.*?】

However, it doesn't work for me. I don't want to remove all of the 【 】 strings. The structure of the citation is what I added as examples. It contains a specific character † between 【 】 and has number(s) or number(s):number(s) before † and doesn't have any special characters other than whitespace, _ and . after †. 
Here are some examples that won't work.
【4A†ABC ABC】

In the example above, the string has the character A before †. The string before † should be just number(s) or number:number such as 4†, 4040†, or 40:1†. So, 4@5†, 4ABC5†, 4$ABC#5†, or something like that won't work.
【4:1ABC ABC】

In the example above, it doesn't have † in it. It should include †.
【45†ABC @#$ 123 ABC】

In the example above, the string after † contains a special character(s). It should not include any special characters(except .) after †.  Only . in the special characters can be included after †.
Hope to get the regex to match all the correct citation cases.

】may be hard to parse for all regex engines. Please show your real input. Does it really have 】and 【 ?

What don’t you want to match?

@TedLyngmo: The [nsregularexpression]  tag says it's unicode, so why should those characters be problematic?

What exactly do you mean by "specific"?

"that worked with the last style": obviously because your regex explicitly wants "source" to be the content between † and 】. I don't understand what you want the requirement to be if it is not that?

Hi all, thanks for the comments. I edited the question. check it if it's more clear.

@TedLyngmo, I am getting like this one when API calls. Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 【4†BD Vid Texts for it 091224.docx】 .  I want to remove the citation 【4†BD Vid Texts for it 091224.docx】 . so it will look like Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum..

@DanielA.White, I edited the question. check it out and let me know if you still have any questions.

@CAustin, the specific I am talking about is because the citation has special characters 【 】. and I want to remove those citations from the result.

@trincot I edited the question. check it out again and let me know if it's not clear.

Why don't you just match any character between the outer boundaries, just in a reluctant way? Like 【.*?】, so that it doesn't match from the start of the first source to the end of the last one but to the nearest end.

I don't understand why you put 'source' in your regex when actually you want to match other content.

@trincot, I said I found one that matches with the last one. I found it online. I wanted to find a regex that matches with the other cases as well. Hope that makes sense.

@cyberbrain, it's similar what I was looking for. But I don't want to remove all of the 【 】 strings. The structure of the citation is what I added as examples. It contains a specific character " † " between 【 】 and has numbers/special character before " † " . Hope this makes sense to you. Can you give me an answer to my question instead of adding comments here?
【4†BD Vid Texts for it 091224.docx】
【4:1†xShort Dashboard Texts.pdf】
【40†source】

"I found it online.": may I then suggest you look at a tutorial on regexes? because just putting "source" makes no sense when you want to match other texts.

It is always like this: \[[^\]\[]*]. In your case, 【\d+(?::\d+)?†[^】【]*】

@WiktorStribiżew, seems it's working. Can you write it as an answer? Also, not sure why this question says "closed".  : (

It is closed because it is not clear to at least 3 SO users. Although I know it is not unclear, it is just another duplicate, there are a lot of posts here about matching inside parentheses/brackets. So, it would have been closed as a dupe otherwise.

I don't understand what you actually want to match, because you didn't add any examples of what not to match - as my suggestion matches your three examples but still is not enough. So maybe you get your actual closing removed by adding that (what is special about the "special citiations" you mentioned) to your question. And maybe it is not a duplicate then anymore - because it is more specific. But no guarantee for that as I still don't see your actual question in your text.

@cyberbrain, thanks for your suggestion.   I updated the question. Check it out and let me know if you still have any questions.

Is there anyone who review this question to reopen it?

@WiktorStribiżew, did you see my comment?

Just seen the new version. It is not clear: you say "the string after † ... should not include any special characters after †." . However, you also say 【4†BD Vid Texts for it 091224.docx】must be matched, but it contains a.` char (a special char).

@WiktorStribiżew, I forgot it. Yes, only . can be included after †. Thanks for your recommendation. I updated the question.

Then, you probably may use 【\d+(?::\d+)?†[\w\s.]*】, see the demo.

Please clarify. From what I understand, after †, you can only have letters, digits, _, whitespaces and dots until the next 】, right?

@WiktorStribiżew, yes, correct!

Then my above solution should work for you. Unless there are some specific Unicode requirements.

@WiktorStribiżew, thanks for your answer and all of your recommendations.  Yes, it seems working fine. Can you mark this question to reopen and write an answer? I will accept your answer.

You can use
【\d+(?::\d+)?†[\w\s.]*】

See the regex demo.
Details:

【 - a 【 char
\d+ - one or more digits
(?::\d+)? - an optional sequence of : and one or more digits
† - a † char
[\w\s.]* - zero or more letters, digits, _, whitespace or . chars
】 - a 】 symbol.

